# MYSQL query to get project details and last MAX() action details from log

Tags: mysql, subquery, max

How can I write a MYSQL query to get project details and the entire last row of the activity log? I want a list of all the projects, with the data from each project's most recent row from the action log, all of it ordered by the most recent action log date DESC. Sorry, I know that this is a common query and the answer must be very easy. But I can't find the solution. I searched with every possible word combination. I found examples that need only one field such as MAX(id) from the joined table. I found solutions with COALESCE but can't seem to make them work. My problem is that I need many fields from the 'parent' table row PL_PROJECTS as well as many fields from the joined table PL_LOG row, not to mention people's names from the same table joined twice.

Everything I try either gives me all the rows of the PL_LOG, repeating rows from PL_PROJECTS. Or, I get just one row from PL_LOG for just one project if I put a LIMIT in the sub query. Here's my query that doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
PJ.pj_id, PJ.pj_title, PJ.pj_location, PJ.pj_desc, PJ.pj_request, PJ.pj_date_start, PP1.pp_name AS supervisor_name, PP2.pp_name AS customer_name, ST.st_desc, logDate, logDesc

FROM PL_PROJECTS PJ 

INNER JOIN PL_PEOPLE PP1 ON PJ.pj_spst_member = PP1.pp_id 

INNER JOIN PL_PEOPLE PP2 ON PJ.pj_pp_id = PP2.pp_id 

INNER JOIN PL_STATUS ST ON PJ.pj_status = ST.st_id 

LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 

    SELECT MAX(lg_pj_id) MaxLogID, lg_date AS logDate, lg_desc AS logDesc, lg_pj_id
    FROM PL_LOG PL
    ORDER BY lg_id DESC

) 

LR ON LR.lg_pj_id = PJ.pj_id 

GROUP BY PJ.pj_id
ORDER BY logDate DESC

LIMIT 9999999
```

Comment: pls give us sample data and the result you expect.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I'm not asking for an MCVE, I'm just asking for help. I know it is a simple and common query!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you problem is, that your subselect only generates one row as you are using max() while you need one row per project (lg_pj_id i think).

You only need to rewrite the subselect to generate one row per project with the informations from the recent activity. Do you have an activity_ID in your action log? Because it looks like 
lg_pj_id is the project_ID. The meaning of lg_desc is also unknown (or is that the action_log_id ?). Try to group by project_ID in you subselect and depending on your needs either select the max values from the corresponding rows or select the row with the maximum values per group (project_ID)

Thanks for the suggestion of GROUP BY to get one row per project. I tried changing the sub-query like so:

```
SELECT MAX(lg_id) AS MaxLogID, lg_desc, lg_pj_id
    FROM PL_LOG PL
    GROUP BY lg_pj_id
```

Now, I get one row from the log, but it gives me the max id, but not the lg_desc from the same row! If I try the sub-query by itself:

```
SELECT lg_id, lg_pj_id, lg_date, lg_desc 
    FROM `PL_LOG` 
    WHERE lg_pj_id = 33 
    ORDER BY lg_date DESC
```

I get these rows. You can see the max row, 68 has a description "30 minute skype call."

```
68,33,2018-06-10 00:00:00","30 minute skype call."

61,33,"2018-06-02 00:00:00","Sent email to try to elicit a response."

52,33,"2018-05-10 00:00:00","sent follow up email"

47,33,"2018-03-26 00:00:00","sent initial email"

46,33,"2018-03-26 00:00:00","sent initial email"
```

But when I try to get just that row, using GROUP BY, it gives me the max lg_id, but the first lg_desc. I need the data all from the max(lg_id) row:

```
SELECT MAX(lg_id) AS MaxLogID, lg_pj_id, lg_date, lg_desc
    FROM PL_LOG
    WHERE lg_pj_id = 33
    GROUP BY lg_pj_id
    ORDER BY MaxLogID DESC
```

Returns:

```
68, 33, "2018-03-26 00:00:00", "sent initial email"
```

Try this as mentioned in my comment:

```
SELECT 
PJ.pj_id, PJ.pj_title, PJ.pj_location, PJ.pj_desc, PJ.pj_request,    
PJ.pj_date_start, PP1.pp_name AS supervisor_name, PP2.pp_name AS 
customer_name, ST.st_desc, logDate, logDesc

FROM PL_PROJECTS PJ 

INNER JOIN PL_PEOPLE PP1 ON PJ.pj_spst_member = PP1.pp_id 

INNER JOIN PL_PEOPLE PP2 ON PJ.pj_pp_id = PP2.pp_id 

INNER JOIN PL_STATUS ST ON PJ.pj_status = ST.st_id 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT lg_id, lg_date AS logDate, lg_desc AS logDesc, lg_pj_id  
           FROM PL_LOG AS PL 
           WHERE PL.lg_id=(SELECT MAX(lg_id) FROM PL_LOG AS PL_2
                           WHERE PL_LOG.lg_pj_id  = PL_2.lg_pj_id )
LR ON LR.lg_pj_id = PJ.pj_id

GROUP BY PJ.pj_id
ORDER BY logDate DESC

LIMIT 9999999
```

Comment: You did edit my answer instead of using the comment function.

Comment: You can select the row with the maximum per group.

Comment: Ok, in the sub-query I have to select all the rows and then join that to another sub-query that returns just the max id for the current project id. It works! Thanks so much. Sorry about editing your answer, I'm (obviously) a newbie here. I see I should have put that in the comment.